# Automatically add comma for monetary values in a form?

Tags: html, jquery

Not sure if I described my question well, but basically here's what I've got right now:

```js
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    ;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="number">
```

Right now if you enter 1000 it will add comma like this: 1,000

What I want is the number to act as a cent.

So if I write 100 it will add a dot here: 1.00

If 1000, then 10.00

If 10000 then 100.00

If 100000 then 1,000.00

and so on.

basically I want the number to be a cent and add commas and dots with a jQuery accordingly.

But I don't want them to be submitted.

I have seen this being done in [ad networks, kubikads](https://www.kubikads.com) for example.
The numbers should be submitted without commas and dots.

The jQuery code in the above code seems very confusing to me .

If anyone have a ready made script or know what to modify in the script to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate

Comment: Do you want 1 to turn into 1 (no change) or 0.01 or 0.1?

Comment: yes, it can turn into 0.01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little dirty... but it works! You can just pop off the decimal and store it while you add the commas.

```js
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/^0+/,"")
      .split(/(\d{0,2})$/)
      .join(".")
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
      .replace(/.$/,"")
  });
});

$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    e.currentTarget[0].value = e.currentTarget[0].value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
    console.log(e.currentTarget[0].value)
    return false; // return false to cancel form action
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
<input class="number">
</form>
```

Comment: hey Daniel, thanks for your effort. It wasn't me who down voted. Anyway, I have tried entering 10, but it won't let me. I can't enter the '0' in the field for some reason...

Comment: Hey Daniel, it works well now, but the dot and commas are submitted. If I enter 100, it will turn as I wanted to 1.00, but it also submits 1.00. I need for 100 to be submitted. Is there any way only the number I enter to be submitted?

Comment: nowhere in this function is submission handled?

Comment: However, if you just run ``` return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")``` before the submission on the field value it will remove all the commas and decimals

Comment: Basically what I want is when a user enter the numbers it will convert into the monetary values, just like you did. Which works great. But when they submit, it would submit without commas and dots.

Comment: Maybe I should have two fields? One which user enter his numbers and it would convert to monetary values with jQuery. Which we have right now, and another which will be  hidden with numbers without commas and dots. And the latter will be submitted?

Comment: Basically when you enter the numbers in the field1 (which will convert as right now), another hidden field2 would fill automatically in a real time, except, without the dots and commas? I guess that would be the best logic.

Comment: You should just parse it on submit. OR preferably parse it in the api (backend) I should how to parse it on submit in the answer now. (not sure if that is the correct place to change it though, I haven't used vanilla js forms in a couple of years)

Comment: If you press enter it "submits" the form (and in the form submission function I console log the parsed value)

Comment: Not really familiar with parsing. I have entered my form id into your code `$('#usp-form-67')`. When I hit submit, the form won't submit. Nothing happens. Not sure why. Anyway, I will accept the answer and either try to figure out myself or ask another question. Thanks for your time Daniel!

Comment: @ricard0 You need to return true instead of false, my bad. it was an example so I didnt want to actually refresh the page.

Comment: Hey Daniel, no problem. I have sorted this problem by adding a second field that will be submitted without commas and dots: https://jsfiddle.net/m81zftwd/1/

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
var num = '132406';  /Your original unformatted number

var ret = '';
var p = 0;

for (let i = num.length; i > 0; i--) {
  p = p + 1;
  if (p == 3 && ret.includes('.') == false) {
    ret = '.' + ret;
    p = 0;
  } else if (p % 3 == 0 ) {
    ret = ',' + ret;
  }
  ret = num.substring(i - 1, i) + ret;
}

console.log(ret);
```